# how to open excel file in python using pandas?

Tags: python, excel

How do you open an xls or csv file in python without having to connect the whole path?

ex: instead of using c:/user/...filename how do you connect it with just filename? 
is it possible using pandas? This is in order to transfer the code from on console to another and the code being able to open with ease. From my understanding, if I use the path and send the code to another computer the excel page won't open there. btw the code will be sent with the original excel sheet

Comment: You can only do that if the file is in the same location as your script or some relative directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I believe you would have to set your working directory to the absolute path of your .py file.

Note, for the code below, your .csv file should be in the same directory as your .py file.

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd

base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # set directory to location of .py file
os.chdir(base_dir) # change directory 
csv_file = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=',') # read .csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to solution of @Ira H., but instead of changing working directory you can generate full path:

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd

base_dir = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath(__file__)
)  # set directory to location of .py file
csv_file = pd.read_csv(f"{base_dir}\\full_paths.csv", sep=",")  # read .csv
```